# ¿Como sacar tasa de éxito?

Tags: sql

Buenas tengo un problema con una consulta, el cual quiero sacar la tasa de éxito de cada trabajador la consulta que tengo es la siguiente:

```
    SELECT
    trabajadores.*,

    tiR.nombre AS docu_revisar_tipos_documento,
    doc1.archivo AS docu_revisar_archivo,
    doc1.estado AS docu_revisar,

    tiC.nombre AS docu_contrato_tipos_documento,
    doc2.archivo AS docu_contrato_archivo,
    doc2.estado AS docu_contrato,

    tiAC.nombre AS docu_anexo_contrato_tipos_documento,
    doc3.archivo AS docu_anexo_contrato_archivo,
    doc3.estado AS docu_anexo_contrato,

    tiEM.nombre AS docu_evalu_medica_tipos_documento,
    doc4.archivo AS docu_evalu_medica_archivo,
    doc4.estado AS docu_evalu_medica,

    tiEP.nombre AS docu_entre_epp_tipos_documento,
    doc5.archivo AS docu_entre_epp_archivo,
    doc5.estado AS docu_entre_epp,

    tiRI.nombre AS docu_ri_tipos_documento,
    doc6.archivo AS docu_ri_archivo,
    doc6.estado AS docu_ri,

    tiCO.nombre AS docu_co_tipos_documento,
    doc7.archivo AS docu_co_archivo,
    doc7.estado AS docu_co,

    tiRUT.nombre AS docu_rut_tipos_documento,
    doc8.archivo AS docu_rut_archivo,
    doc8.estado AS docu_rut,

    SUM(CASE WHEN doc1.estado = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN doc2.estado = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN doc3.estado = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN doc4.estado = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN doc5.estado = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN doc6.estado = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN doc7.estado = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN doc8.estado = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) total_exitoso,

    COUNT(doc1.estado) D1,
    COUNT(doc2.estado) D2,
    COUNT(doc3.estado) D3,
    COUNT(doc4.estado) D4,
    COUNT(doc5.estado) D5,
    COUNT(doc6.estado) D6,
    COUNT(doc7.estado) D7,
    COUNT(doc8.estado) D8

FROM
    trabajadores
LEFT JOIN trabajadores_documento doc1 ON
    trabajadores.id = doc1.fk_id_trabajador AND doc1.fk_id_tipos_documentos = 1
LEFT JOIN trabajadores_documento doc2 ON
    trabajadores.id = doc2.fk_id_trabajador AND doc2.fk_id_tipos_documentos = 2
LEFT JOIN trabajadores_documento doc3 ON
    trabajadores.id = doc3.fk_id_trabajador AND doc3.fk_id_tipos_documentos = 3
LEFT JOIN trabajadores_documento doc4 ON
    trabajadores.id = doc4.fk_id_trabajador AND doc4.fk_id_tipos_documentos = 4
LEFT JOIN trabajadores_documento doc5 ON
    trabajadores.id = doc5.fk_id_trabajador AND doc5.fk_id_tipos_documentos = 5
LEFT JOIN trabajadores_documento doc6 ON
    trabajadores.id = doc6.fk_id_trabajador AND doc6.fk_id_tipos_documentos = 6
LEFT JOIN trabajadores_documento doc7 ON
    trabajadores.id = doc7.fk_id_trabajador AND doc7.fk_id_tipos_documentos = 7
LEFT JOIN trabajadores_documento doc8 ON
    trabajadores.id = doc8.fk_id_trabajador AND doc8.fk_id_tipos_documentos = 8
LEFT JOIN tipos_documentos tiR ON
    doc1.fk_id_tipos_documentos = tiR.id
LEFT JOIN tipos_documentos tiC ON
    doc2.fk_id_tipos_documentos = tiC.id
LEFT JOIN tipos_documentos tiAC ON
    doc3.fk_id_tipos_documentos = tiAC.id
LEFT JOIN tipos_documentos tiEM ON
    doc4.fk_id_tipos_documentos = tiEM.id
LEFT JOIN tipos_documentos tiEP ON
    doc5.fk_id_tipos_documentos = tiEP.id
LEFT JOIN tipos_documentos tiRI ON
    doc6.fk_id_tipos_documentos = tiRI.id
LEFT JOIN tipos_documentos tiCO ON
    doc7.fk_id_tipos_documentos = tiCO.id
LEFT JOIN tipos_documentos tiRUT ON
    doc8.fk_id_tipos_documentos = tiRUT.id
ORDER BY
    trabajadores.id
DESC
```

El cual me funciona bien pero siempre y cuando el trabajador tiene documentos subidos, cuando agrego un nuevo trabajador en el listado ese no me aparece ya que no tiene documentos por ende debe mostrarse para asi cargarle documentos

En el siguiente link pueden ver el funcionamiento de las tablas que estoy utilizando

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79349d/1

La tasa de éxito o el cumplimento del trabajador, en el ejemplo del SQL están estas columnas:

**total_exitoso D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8**

entonces su tasa de éxito tiene que ser:

**total_exitoso/D1,D2,D3,ETC *100** para asi poder tener un porcentaje de cada trabajador

Gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías definir cómo calculas la tasa de éxito? Me has descolocado totalmente con tantas combinaciones a la misma tabla. Genial por aportar el SQL de la base de datos, ¿nos explicas un poco la semántica?

Comment: Fijate la tasa de exito o el cumpliento del trabajador vendria siendo el siguiente:

Si te fijas en el ejemplo del SQL estan estas columnas:

total_exitoso    D1    D2    D3    D4    D5    D6    D7    D8

entonces su tasa de exito tiene que ser: **total_exitoso/D1,D2,D3,ETC *100**

Comment: La idea de esto, es poder ver en que porcentaje tiene el cumplimento cada trabajador

Comment: ¿Haz podido ver lo de la consulta? gracias

Comment: Todo esto que comentas es mejor que lo incluyas en la pregunta. Estaría bien que pudieras darme más detalles en un chat, pero necesitas 20 puntos. Voy a abrirlo y a ver si localizo a un moderador para que te admita. Entretanto, vete modificando la pregunta

Comment: Por favor, seria muy bien eso quedo atento gracias

Comment: Ok, intenta acceder al chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91357/query-mysql Si no puedes, conecta conmigo vía likedin y ya localizamos a un moderador

Comment: No puedo acceder, como hago para contactarte por likedin ?

Comment: @David ya te envie la solicitud.

Comment: sql sobre que base de datos? por lo que se ve parece mysql, ya que usas funciones de agrupacion sin un group by. Y eso es muy malo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la conversación del chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91357/query-mysql, adjunto la solución alcanzada:

```
SELECT *,fk_id_trabajador,n_completos/n_subidos*100 tasa_exito FROM (
    SELECT fk_id_trabajador,COUNT(*) n_subidos
      FROM trabajadores_documento
  ) c1 JOIN (
    SELECT fk_id_trabajador,COUNT(*) n_completos
      FROM trabajadores_documento WHERE estado=4
  ) c2 USING(fk_id_trabajador) RIGHT JOIN trabajadores
  ON c1.fk_id_trabajador=trabajadores.id;
```

Habíamos llegado a otras soluciones intermedias bastante interesantes con un producto cartesiano y un producto externo combinado por dos campos:

```
SELECT *,IFNULL(estado=4,0) exito FROM (
    SELECT trabajadores.id id_trabajador,
           rut,nombres,apellidos,f_nacimiento,
           sexo,tipos_documentos.id id_documento,nombre
      FROM trabajadores,tipos_documentos  
  ) c1 LEFT JOIN trabajadores_documento
  ON fk_id_trabajador=id_trabajador
  AND fk_id_tipos_documentos=id_documento
  ORDER BY id_trabajador,id_documento;
```

Pero no eran lo buscado. Había bastante miga...

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)